# Is there a way that I can leverage a JSON Schema to flag / classify an attribute as PII

Tags: json, jsonschema, pii

If I have a JSON Schema file that has an email attribute:
{
"from": {
"title": "From email address",
"type": "email"
}
}

Is there any way, using standard schema JSON keywords to identify property "from" as a "PII" property?
It would be great to be able to define your own:
{
"from": {
"title": "From email address",
"type": "email",
"pii": true
}
}

I browsed through the JSON schema definitions / docs at https://cswr.github.io/JsonSchema/spec/definitions_references/ and could not find something that would work.

Comment: what is wrong with adding new field? can you explain better what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: This discussion didn't really get very far with the maintainers.  But you can feel free to add to that discussion, your examples and use case.  Ben Hutton commented a custom vocabulary would be ideal for this, this would be a custom keyword definition which can be included in Draft 2020-12 schemas.  https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues/1182
more information on vocabs:
https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-vocabularies

Comment: btw, the official json-schema docs are located at https://json-schema.org   the link you provided for docs is an implementation of the JSON Schema specification, not the official one.

Comment: What am I trying to accomplish? I use a JSON Schema file to validate a JSON payload (API POST) and when I parse the payload I need to handle attributes that are PII classified differently. E.g. PII data needs to be encrypted and stored in a mutable database whereas the rest of the attributes are going to be stored in an immutable database (SQL ledger).

Comment: Since PII data is sensitive (needs encrypting) and also needs to be able to be deleted it cannot be stored in SQL Ledger. I was hoping to leverage the JSON schema file so as to code in logic that will allow the user to call out PII relevant properties in the schema file so as to provide a no-code approach to handle PII data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with JSON Schema annotations. The annotations feature is just a way to add meta data to a JSON instance. You can then write code to process the JSON how you wish based on those annotations.

An annotation can be as simple as a custom keyword that you choose to use in your schema. Your `pii` keyword is sufficient.

There aren't too many JSON Schema implementations out there that provide annotation data, and almost all of them just give the data and you have to parse it yourself to get what you need. I've written some javascript tooling that makes working with annotations a little easier, but there's nothing like it in other languages as far as I'm aware.

```js
import { annotate } from "@hyperjump/json-schema/annotations/experimental";
import * as Instance from "@hyperjump/json-schema/annotated-instance/experimental";
import { addSchema } from "@hyperjump/json-schema/draft-2020-12";
import * as JsonPointer from "@hyperjump/json-pointer";


(async function () {
  const schemaId = "https://example.com/foo";
  const dialectId = "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema";

  addSchema({
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "name": { "type": "string" },
      "email": {
        "type": "string",
        "format": "email",
        "pii": true
      }
    }
  }, schemaId, dialectId);

  const data = {
    name: "Jason",
    email: "jason@example.com"
  };
  const instance = await annotate(schemaId, data);

  let encrypted = data;
  for (const pii of Instance.annotatedWith(instance, "pii", dialectId)) {
    encrypted = JsonPointer.set(pii.pointer, encrypted, encrypt(Instance.value(pii)));
  }

  console.log(encrypted);
}());
```

Output

```json
{
  "name": "Jason",
  "email": "ENCRYPTED--jason@example.com--ENCRYPTED"
}
```

(Insert your own `encrypt` function that actually encrypts.)